# org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, jersey, weblogic12c

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4DY46f-LZ0M). And I followed the steps. But I am getting this error:

```
 org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to deploy. See Error Log view for more detail.
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deployAutoGenerateEarApplication(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:806)......
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1425)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:917)
Contains: Module named '_auto_generated_ear_' failed to start.
Contains: weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "Jersey REST Service" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "com.restful.oracle.weblogic.youtube".
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig     instance does not contain any root resource classes.
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
:com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException:The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver. See Error Log view for more detail.
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:189)
at oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.startModule(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:1127)
Caused by: weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "Jersey REST Service" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "com.restful.oracle.weblogic.youtube".
com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
```

My web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>com.restful.oracle.weblogic.youtube</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>readme.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.restful.oracle.weblogic.youtube</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>*</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

I have jersey 1.9.1 add to this project. I am new in rest or weblogic.
I also looked at Stackoverflow but didn't help.
Can you help me out with this? If any information do you need please post as comments.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after adding a new servlet and removing it.
The web.xml wasn't updated after removing and I needed to remove the references there to the deleted servlet.
Remove this for example:

```
 <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>Configuration</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Configuration</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.Configuration</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Configuration</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Configuration</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason of the problem is that the deployed war file is not created properly. I strongly recommend that you should export war file by right-click->export->war and check the war file content with 7zip/winrar etc.